# Monopoly cheaters edition railways and "road blocks"

Tags: monopoly-cheaters-edition

My family arguments regarding block card and railway station.

The rules state when you roll the dice and you land on railway station you have to move straight to the next nearest railway station.
But when I landed on a station my opponent had a card that said "road blocked: players passing this property must stop and pay rent to the owner" before the next station.
Does this mean that I have to stop there or not?
Because the rules say when you land on Railway station you have to move to the next nearest station should I also skip the "Road blocked" card and go straight to the next station?

Comment: Turns out there is a 'cheaters edition'  I've taken house rule tag off and updated the tags.  https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/254617/monopoly-cheaters-edition.

Comment: @Mary Could you help clarify question as I don't think its clear what your asking.  eg. "it said when..." what it 'It'?

Comment: [Found an overview of the game](https://youtu.be/MJ4dZ-rxHaU) for those interested, but @MaryPardey, we need to know what you mean by "it" in "it said". do you mean the rules booklet?

Comment: Does the rule about moving to the next railway say "Advance to", or "Go directly to"?  (In other words, if you passed Go, would you collect $200?)

Answer (score -1):

NO. You don't have to stop. When it says go straight to the next station, you can not be affected by anything else unless you pass go of cause, in which case you will get 200 bucks. You definitely do not have to stop in another's property. Think of it as you are teleporting to your target.

Comment: A) this answer would be improved by rule references, and B) if you're teleporting directly there, why do you get $200?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Consider $200 as a special rule. Sorry about those mistakes. This is my 1st answer. Can you edit to improve?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about Monopoly Cheaters Edition.  I'm afraid you're on your own.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Someone will edit it then...

Comment: This question has gone unanswered for over a year because none of the regular SE members are familiar with the game.  If we *had* the rule references, we'd have answered it already.  You are perfectly capable of supporting your own answer.